# UYVY format to be converted

Tags: image-processing, video-processing

I' m framing video images from video stream and I took one frame of the video streaming from a video Port (as a first step of my application) so I could transmit the raw UYVY video data. After running, these data are stored  into a .dat file

Meanwhile, before transmitting the raw data, I am looking for a way to display the decoded information stored in the .dat file. In other words, Is there a software that would convert the UYVY raw data into a picture?

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: `UYVY` makes already a picture, you could - under certain conditions - display directly. What OS and language you are looking leads for?

Answer (score 0):

Each of your .dat file is an UYVY 422 image that can be display.
Without any details about your platform and your running context, I would recommend the use of the FFMPEG suite.

Using ffplay you could display your image with

```
 ffplay -video_size WIDTHxHEIGHT -pixel_format uyvy422 filename.dat
```

As you saw the only things you need to know is the image size!